# '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I'm writing a code to implement k-fold cross validation.

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data_assignment1.csv')
k=10

np.random.shuffle(data.values)  # Shuffle all rows
folds = np.array_split(data, k) # split the data into k folds

for i in range(k):
    x_cv = folds[i][:, 0]  # Set ith fold for testing
    y_cv = folds[i][:, 1]
    new_folds = np.row_stack(np.delete(folds, i, 0)) # Remove ith fold for training
    x_train = new_folds[:, 0]  # Set the remaining folds for training
    y_train = new_folds[:, 1]
```

When trying to set the values for x_cv and y_cv, I get the error:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

In an attempt to solve this, I tried using folds.iloc[i][:, 0].values etc:

```
for i in range(k):
    x_cv = folds.iloc[i][:, 0].values  # Set ith fold for testing
    y_cv = folds.iloc[i][:, 1].values
    new_folds = np.row_stack(np.delete(folds, i, 0)) # Remove ith fold for training
    x_train = new_folds.iloc[:, 0].values  # Set the remaining folds for training
    y_train = new_folds.iloc[:, 1].values
```

I then got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `folds = np.array_split(data, k)` will return a `list of Dataframes`.
2. `type(folds) == list`
3. This is why you got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'`.
   `List` objects dont have the `iloc` method.
4. So you need to first access list with index first to get each DataFrame object. `folds[i]`.
5. `type(folds[i]) == pandas.DataFrame`
6. Now use `iloc` on the `DataFrame` object.
7. `folds[i].iloc[:,0].values`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to plot using **matplotlib**, solve the problem by using

```py
plt.scatter(X.iloc[:,0], X.iloc[:,1], s=40, c=y, cmap='winter')
```

instead of :

```py
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=40, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.BuGn)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).